# Possible bug in displaying new "questions with new activity" for 2 or more tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, live-refresh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When I search for certain tags, the “X new questions with update” comes up only one one of the tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128126/when-i-search-for-certain-tags-the-x-new-questions-with-update-comes-up-only)

"questions with new activity" (when two tags or more are selected) may contain questions that include only one requested tag.

### Steps to reproduce

1. Login to SO
2. Enter `[vim] [javascript]` into the `search` input
3. Switch to the `active` tab
4. Wait until `"1 new question with new activity"` bar appears. Once it appeared click on it.
5. Newly appeared question is tagged with `[javascript]` tag but not with `[vim]` tag.

### Expected behavior

Newly appeared question from step 5 must be tagged with both `[javascript]` and `[vim]` tags.