# When I search for certain tags, the "X new questions with update" comes up only one one of the tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, live-refresh

I just did [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+windows-authentication)

Because I wanted to find all questions with both [php](/questions/tagged/php) and [windows-authentication](/questions/tagged/windows-authentication).

So I ran the search and got the page with 4 results.

When I waited for a bit I saw that there were some new questions with activity:

[image: tag activity]

But when I click on it, the new questions **do not** completely have to do with my query:

[image: tag none]

None of those updated have to do with [windows-authentication](/questions/tagged/windows-authentication). And then when I refresh the page again, it is back down to the 4 that I had originally found.

Comment: Yeah, looks like it subscribes to each tag individually, which is incorrect in this case.

Comment: I have observed the same behavior too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After the next deploy we will support both the AND and the OR operators on tags for realtime updates which will fix this issue.  If your tags contain a combination of both AND / OR operators updates will be disabled and you'll need to go back to wearing out your F5 key.

Comment: Geoff I have a question, when I don't add any `AND` or `OR` in the search bar like `[c#][datetime]`, the page stays on `/questions/tagged/` page (like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+datetime) and it updates automatically when new question added with these tags, when I add `AND` or `OR`, the pages goes to `/search?tab` (like https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bc%23%5d%20AND%20%5bdatetime%5d). Does this `/search?tab` page have such a functionality that updated itself automatically when added a new question?